# Can FreeOpcUa python be used to generate a custom event with a set of nodeIds?

Tags: opc-ua

From my OPC-UA server I want to generate a custom event. The custom event shall contain a set of "nodes".
Each "node" shall contain nodeId, parent nodeId and node name.
Is that possible using https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can use the `server-event` example:
https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/blob/master/examples/server-events.py

It contains the creation of custom events.

Comment: I have seen that example. Since freeopcua do not support model change event I want to use custom event to emulate a model change event. So I am really asking for a way to include node information in the custom event for a set of new nodes.